# Castle always load the first component when resolving a service

Tags: components, castle

I have two components for the same service type. When running the application,Castle always load the first component. For example I have one `IDbConfiguration` service which points to different Databases, and two components for `IDbconfiguration`:

```
<component id="DbConfig" 
    service="Maloft.Keryx.Infrastructure.RepositoryFramework.IDbConfiguration, Keryx.Infrastructure"
    type="Maloft.Keryx.Infrastructure.RepositoryFramework.DbConfiguration, Keryx.Infrastructure"
    lifeStyle="PerWebRequest"/>
    <parameters>
        <connectionName>kerxy</connectionName>
    </parameters>
<component id="DbReportingConfig"                    
    service="Maloft.Keryx.Infrastructure.RepositoryFramework.IDbConfiguration, Keryx.Infrastructure"          
    type="Maloft.Keryx.Infrastructure.RepositoryFramework.DbConfiguration, Keryx.Infrastructure"
    lifeStyle="PerWebRequest">
    <parameters>
        <connectionName>kerxyReporting</connectionName>
    </parameters>
</component>
```

The component `PlayerRepository` depends on `DbReportingConfig`, `PlayerDomainService` depends on `PlayerRepository`, but when i resolve any of these service they always load the first `DbConfig`.

Changing the order in the xml file shows that the first component for IDbConfiguration is the one used each time. I have set different Ids for these two components, why is the first one always loaded?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That behavior is expected: from the [docs](http://docs.castleproject.org/Windsor.Registering-components-one-by-one.ashx)

> In Windsor first one wins In Castle, the default implementation for a
>   service is the first registered implementation. This is different from
>   AutoFac for example, where the default is the last registered
>   implementation
>   (http://code.google.com/p/autofac/wiki/ComponentCreation).

Now if you want to resolve a specific component in a specific context you should take a look at [service override](http://docs.castleproject.org/Windsor.Registering-components-one-by-one.ashx#Supplying_the_component_for_a_dependency_to_use_Service_override_9) or [dependencies](http://docs.castleproject.org/Windsor.Inline-Dependencies.ashx) (I'm more familiar with the latter, which I find more explicit).

I don't use xml configuration in Windsor but [this page](http://docs.castleproject.org/Windsor.Registering-components.ashx#Service_overrides_other_service_as_parameter_4) should help you setting up service overrides